# Getting more than two counts in one query

Tags: sql-server

scenario: I have table A and Table B. Both have the primary key of Rep_time_frame. We replicate data by terms. however, that process at times was repeated.

task:  Match the source counts with the destination table counts.

problem: I can match the rows of the source table but not the destination table because the replication for some terms happened twice. So, my counts are off.

````
SELECT  d.REPT_TIME_FRAME, 
        c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS, 
        COUNT(*) TOTAL_RECORDS, 
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(*) > c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS THEN c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS
                ELSE COUNT(*)
            END FINAL_TOTAL_RECORDS,
            ***CASE
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT REPT_TIME_FRAME
                             FROM TableA_Counts
                             WHERE REPT_TIME_FRAME IN (201705, 201708, 201801, 201706, 201710, 201803)
                             GROUP BY REPT_TIME_FRAME
                             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) THEN 'UPLOADED MORE THAN ONCE'
                ELSE'UPLOADED ONCE'
            END NUMBER_OF_REPLICATIONS***
FROM TableA d
INNER JOIN TableA_Counts c ON (d.REPT_TIME_FRAME = c.REPT_TIME_FRAME)
WHERE d.REPT_TIME_FRAME IN (201705, 201708, 201801, 201706, 201710, 201803)
GROUP BY d.REPT_TIME_FRAME,  c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS```


please note that the bolded area, when ran returns for the newly made column Number_of_replications "Uploaded More than once" on all counts. For the purposes of this example. Here are the facts.

201705 was replicated 2X
201801 once and 201708 once.

expected result. I want to have 201705 'Uploaded more than once', and the rest 201801 and 201708 'Uploaded Once'
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8692a/1

I always try and get the counts then do a case statement on the final figures. I've based that SqlFiddle on the notion that TableA_Counts is the table with more than one entry for 201705. Is that correct?

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (REPT_TIME_FRAME int)
INSERT INTO TableA(REPT_TIME_FRAME)VALUES 
(201705),
(201708),
(201801), 
(201706), 
(201710),
(201803 )

CREATE TABLE TableA_Counts (REPT_TIME_FRAME int)
INSERT INTO TableA_Counts(REPT_TIME_FRAME)VALUES 
(201705),
(201708),
(201705),
(201801), 
(201706), 
(201710),
(201803)


SELECT 
d.REPT_TIME_FRAME,count(*) as TOTAL_RECORDS,SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS,
CASE WHEN SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS > 1 then 'more than' else 'just one' end as NUMBER_OF_REPLICATIONS
FROM
TableA d
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT REPT_TIME_FRAME ,count(*) as SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS from TableA_Counts group by REPT_TIME_FRAME) c  ON (d.REPT_TIME_FRAME = c.REPT_TIME_FRAME)
group by d.REPT_TIME_FRAME,SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS
```

Comment: @Hakka-4 If it is the answer, can your mark my post please? Everyone needs Karma :P

Comment: It says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.", I tried several times. Not sure how to give you credit but you did help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  d.REPT_TIME_FRAME, 
        c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS, 
        COUNT(*) TOTAL_RECORDS, 
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(*) > c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS THEN c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS
                ELSE COUNT(*)
            END FINAL_TOTAL_RECORDS,
        a.count AS NUM_OF_REPLICATIONS
FROM TableA d
INNER JOIN TableACounts c ON (d.REPT_TIME_FRAME = c.REPT_TIME_FRAME)
INNER JOIN (SELECT REPT_TIME_FRAME ,count(REPT_TIME_FRAME) as count
            FROM TableAcounts
            WHERE REPT_TIME_FRAME IN (201705, 201708, 201801, 201706, 201710, 201803)
            GROUP BY REPT_TIME_FRAME) AS a ON (a.REPT_TIME_FRAME = d.REPT_TIME_FRAME)
WHERE d.REPT_TIME_FRAME IN (201705, 201708, 201801, 201706, 201710, 201803)
GROUP BY d.REPT_TIME_FRAME,  c.SOURCE_TOTAL_RECORDS, a.count
```